# Analysis: Showing convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I show that if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is a convergent series, with $a_n>0$ and supposing that $b_n>0$ is a bounded sequence that the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_nb_n)$$

is convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Throughout the proof we will use the fact that $a_n,b_n>0$)

Since $b_n$ is bounded, we have $b_n < M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Hence, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n b_n < \sum_{n=0}^N a_n \cdot M = M \sum_{n=0}^N a_n$$
Hence, we can conclude that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n b_n < M \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$$